# Ajax-Solr does not query or find the Solr Server

Tags: ajax, solr, nutch

I set up a little search server with Apache Nutch, Solr and Ajax-Solr as a Frontend. If i am using the solr server out of the ajax-solr tutorial everything is working fine but if i am going to use my own solr server (runns on the same computer) my frontend seems to search the server but didn't find it. 
I searched with google and here in the forum but i did not find something that's working.
Has anyone an idea what went wrong?
(Solr server is starting without any exceptions)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to see the search query being issued by UI in SOLR logs? Try using firebug to debug the javascript..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer. I checked everything with firebug and found the Problem. There was just a missing field declaration in the reuters.js

Now the search Server works great.